# Tiny MCE conflict with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

I am using sb admin 2 theme from Bootstrap and I have a Tiny MCE area for editing HTML. When I click on something on the Tiny MCE that shows modal form, the modal form looks broken. Here are few screenshots.

http://gyazo.com/f271ce6c55f367fd528af20de15d6c72

http://gyazo.com/7827067aecc7d294b16153b013fb79b4

I was trying to find a way to disable the Bootstrap CSS for certain area inside the HTML, but I don't think that this is possible. Any help will be appreciated.